# Automate the process of uploading a new build to a website. i.e. npm run build -> cpanel upload

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, automation, cpanel

I am managing a mostly static site through GoDaddy.

The site is a React single page application, that is still currently under development, and that occasionally needs content updating. The project folder is hosted as a public git repository.

My goal is to be able to automate the process of updating the site. Currently I need to:

1. npm run build
2. navigate to the build folder in windows file explorer
3. navigate to the public html folder in cpanel, in my web browser
4. delete the current build files
5. upload the contents of the build files into cpanel, folder by folder (cpanel will not allow me to upload subfolders)

I have looked through countless forum posts, and blogs, etc to find a way to automate this, but I always end up doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate using continuous deployment (CD/CI) and using a different hosting setup. Unfortunately, the type of platform that you use (with CPanel) is limiting and is not really oriented at your use case.

**However**, [CPanel does have an option to use Git version control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmqG3.png) to manage the files and folders in your account. Go into this option and say "Clone repository", where you'll have to link a repo and say where it should install. *Note: It is possible that your hosting provider has disabled this feature.*

I suspect that this CPanel feature does not automatically pull in changes when you update the repo, so you would probably still need to manually clone the repo again when you make changes (which is still easier than copying files over). Also note that any data you store may be removed when cloning again.